# How do I prove that if $S$ is onto then $T$ cannot be one-to-one?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Let $T: \Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}^4$ and $S: \Bbb{R}^4 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ be two linear transformations such that the composition $S\circ T=0$.

How can I show that if $S$ is onto, then $T$ cannot be one-to-one?

Comment: I tried using the dimensions but I faced a different error each time @ArpitKansal

Answer (score 3):

If $S$ is onto the $\dim\ker S=4-2$. If $T$ is one-to-one then $\dim\operatorname{im}T=3$. If $S\circ T=0$ then $\operatorname{im}T\subseteq \ker S$.

Comment: So we proceeded by contradiction?

Comment: What are the ker and im  ?

Comment: Your answer is nice.